# difference between did have to and had to

Tags: syntax

Do these two sentence mean the same? must/should in past

I did have to play football.
I had to play football. - And here after 'had to' to comes infinitive ?

Are these two sentences the same and are they both correct?

Answer (score 2):

**They're both grammatically correct, but they don't mean exactly the same thing.**

The normal way of expressing *have to* in the past is simply **had to**, as in your second example sentence.  For example,

> Today I have to go to the office.  Yesterday I **had to** go to the store.

Your first sentence, "I did have to play football", looks like an example of the [emphatic *do*](http://grammar.about.com/od/e/g/Emphatic-do.htm).  This is the use of *to do* as an auxiliary verb to give emphasis to something.  For example, if someone said to you, "...but you didn't have to go to the store yesterday," you might respond, "No, I **did** have to go to the store yesterday."  Or you might say, "I didn't have to play football in school, but I **did** have to play tennis," to emphasize the contrast.

Note that the negation of "have to" in the present or past always uses *do*, as in

> I have to eat

vs

> I don't have to eat.

or

> I had to eat

vs

> I didn't have to eat.

but in a positive sense, like "I did have to eat", *do* is not normally necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but as far as I know, the negation of "have to" not always needs the auxiliary DO.

Only with nouns (didn't have + noun).

When it comes to verbs, you don't use the auxiliary DO: (hadn't + verb).

EXAMPLES:

"I didn't have money at that moment"  (didn't have + noun).

"I hadn't saved any money until that moment" (hadn't + verb).

"I hadn't slept/heard" (hadn't + verb).